# Circles partitioning the plane

Tags: geometry, circles, integer-partitions

What is the equation for the  maximum number of regions into which N circles can partition a plane? Is there a name for this equation?

A single circle partitions the plane into two regions, inside and out.

First few outputs:

> - 1 circle  2 regions
> - 2 circles 4 regions
> - 3 circles 8 regions
> - 4 circles 14 regions

Comment: related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190914/do-circles-divide-the-plane-into-more-regions-than-lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is $C_{n} = n^2 - n + 2$.  See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlaneDivisionbyCircles.html.

I don't know a specific name for this, but I assume "Plane Division by Circles Equation" might work.

If you want me to prove why this equation is correct, let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I had arrived at the equation  C_n= n*(n-1)+2 and was having a hard time finding a source to confirm it.